# Converting element classes to a selector

Tags: jquery

using `$(elem).attr("class")` or `elem.className` return a space seperated list of class names

Is there a better way to turn this in to a selector than

```
"." + classNamesString.split(" ").join(".")
```

**Example**

```
<div class="a b c"></div>
<div class="a b c"></div>
<div class="a b c"></div>
<div class="a b c"></div>
<div class="a b d"></div>
<div class="a b c"></div>
<div class="a b c"></div>

$("a").click(function(){

  var classNames = $(this).attr("class");
  $("body").find( < use classNames > ).colorBlue();

});
```

I am trying to avoid tiny utility functions and searching for some jQueryesque way to do it, if possible

Comment: Why do you need this? If you already have `elem` stored in a variable, why do you need to select it again?

Comment: I guess this is the best and clean way.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Looks like he wants to select all elements that share the classes

Comment: I want to take the classes and use find() on it, but since it doesn't return a selector I was wondering if there is a better way to do it

Comment: Can you pls add some sample markup and selectors you're trying ?

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify it a little by just replacing spaces with periods:

```
"." + classNamesString.replace(/ /g,".")
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

html

```
<div class="hai bye hello">Text</div>
```

jquery be

```
$("." + $('div').attr('class').split(" ").join(", .")).click(function() {

   alert('hello') 
});
```

your context be

```
 $("body").find("." + $('div').attr('class').split(" ").join(", .")).css('color', 'blue');
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hs340ozm/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector if similar classes are always set in same order in HTML markup:

```
$("body").find( '[class="' + classNamesString + '"]' ).colorBlue();
```

Answer (score 0):

here if you can try:

`var class_element = ($(element).attr("class")).split(" ").join(", .");
$(class_element).yourfunction();`

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```js
$("div").click(function() {

  var classNames = $(this).attr("class");
  var _selector = $("body *").filter(function() {
    return this.className === classNames
  });
  _selector.css("color", "blue");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a b c">abc</div>
<div class="a b c">abc</div>
<div class="a b c">abc</div>
<div class="a b c">abc</div>
<div class="a b c">abc</div>
<div class="a b c">abc</div>
<div class="d e f">def</div>
<div class="a b c">abc</div>
```